# Expectation and Variance

Tags: probability, expectation, invariance

I was asked to give a simple example to show that $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ is not necessarily true if and when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. I can't seem to find a simple example without ending with a proof by induction. Thanks.

Comment: @LeilaHatami And yet another useless edit. Well done.

Comment: @Did Your welcome... I'm still waiting for coupling. Contribute!

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=-1$ with probability $1/2$, and let  $X=1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $Y=X$.

Comment: oh ok thanks... and I guess same would go for showing that Var[X+Y] = Var[X] + Var[Y] is not necessarily true when both variables X,Y are not independent then?

Comment: Yes, it can be done that way, but  there is a way with even less work. Let $X=Y$. Then $X+Y=2X$, and the variance of $2X$ is $4$ times the variance of $X$. This would be variance of $X$ plus the variance of $Y$, that is, twice the variance of $X$ only in the degenerate case variance equals $0$.

Comment: awesome thanks. very helpful and prompt.

Comment: You are welcome. More interesting is finding examples where $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. For that, let for example $X=-1,0,1$ with $\Pr(X=-1)=\Pr(X=1)=1/3$ and let $Y=X^2$. By symmetry both $E(X)$ and $E(X^3)$ are $0$.